# How can I rethrow Exception?

Tags: java, exception

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to throw an exception without adding the throws declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519557/is-there-a-way-to-throw-an-exception-without-adding-the-throws-declaration)

I wonder if there is a way to encapsulate `Exception` and rethrow it in another `Exception` when method is already defined and don't have `throws` clause.

An example (with JMS `onMessage` method) :

```
 public void onMessage(Message message) {

    if(message instanceof ObjectMessage){

        ObjectMessage objectMessage = (ObjectMessage)message;

        try {
            Object object = objectMessage.getObject();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            throw new CustomException("blah blah", e); // ERROR HERE : Unhandled exception type CustomException
        }

     }

 }
```

So, how can I encapsulate and dispatch `CustomException` in my code please ? Is there a way ? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a subclass of `RuntimeException`.

Answer (score 3):

If a method does not declare any exceptions, the only way is to throw an exception which subclasses of `RuntimeException`.

In your case `CustomException` should extend `RuntimeException`.

A bit of theory from [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html) on Exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

This would have worked if CustomException was an unchecked exception (run time exception). You can read about checked vs unchecked exceptions here -
[Java: checked vs unchecked exception explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation)