# A peculiar feature of exception type inference in Java 8

Tags: java, generics, java-8, type-inference

While writing code for another answer on this site I came across this peculiarity:

```
static void testSneaky() {
  final Exception e = new Exception();
  sneakyThrow(e);    //no problems here
  nonSneakyThrow(e); //ERRROR: Unhandled exception: java.lang.Exception
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
static <T extends Throwable> void sneakyThrow(Throwable t) throws T {
  throw (T) t;
}

static <T extends Throwable> void nonSneakyThrow(T t) throws T {
  throw t;
}
```

First, I am quite confused why the `sneakyThrow` call is OK to the compiler. What possible type did it infer for `T` when there is no mention anywhere of an unchecked exception type?

Second, accepting that this works, why then does the compiler complain on the `nonSneakyThrow` call? They seem very much alike.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The T of `sneakyThrow` is inferred to be `RuntimeException`. This can be followed from the langauge spec on type inference (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html)

Firstly, there's a note in section 18.1.3:

> A bound of the form `throws α` is purely informational: it directs resolution to optimize the instantiation of α so that, if possible, it is not a checked exception type.

This doesn't affect anything, but it points us to the Resolution section (18.4), which has got more information on inferred exception types with a special case:

> ... Otherwise, if the bound set contains `throws αi`, and the proper upper bounds of αi are, at most, `Exception`, `Throwable`, and `Object`, then Ti = `RuntimeException`.

This case applies to `sneakyThrow` - the only upper bound is `Throwable`, so `T` is inferred to be `RuntimeException` as per the spec, so it compiles. The body of the method is immaterial - the unchecked cast succeeds at runtime because it doesn't actually happen, leaving a method that can defeat the compile-time checked exception system.

`nonSneakyThrow` does not compile as that method's `T` has got a lower bound of `Exception` (ie `T` must be a supertype of `Exception`, or `Exception` itself), which is a checked exception, due to the type it's being called with, so that `T` gets inferred as `Exception`.

Comment: @Maksym You must mean the `sneakyThrow` call. The special regulations about the inference of `throws T` forms did not exist in the specification of Java 7.

Comment: Small nitpick: In `nonSneakyThrow`, `T` must be `Exception`, not "a supertype of" `Exception`, because it is exactly the type of the argument declared at compile time at the call site.

Comment: @llogiq If I've read the spec correctly, it's got a lower bound of `Exception` and an upper bound of `Throwable`, so the least upper bound, which is the resulting inferred type, is `Exception`.

Comment: @llogiq Note that the type of the argument only sets a lower type bound because any supertype of the argument is also acceptable.

Comment: the “or `Exception` itself” phrase might be helpful to the reader but generally, it should be noted that the specification always uses the terms “subtype” and “supertype” in the sense of “including itself”…

Answer (score 19):

If type inference produces a single upper bound for a type variable, typically the upper bound is chosen as the solution. For example, if `T<<Number`, the solution is `T=Number`. Although `Integer`, `Float` etc. could also satisfy the constraint, there's no good reason to choose them over `Number`.

That was also the case for `throws T` in java 5-7: `T<<Throwable  =>  T=Throwable`. (Sneaky throw solutions all had explicit `<RuntimeException>` type arguments, otherwise `<Throwable>` is inferred.)

In java8, with the introduction of lambda, this becomes problematic. Consider this case

```
interface Action<T extends Throwable>
{
    void doIt() throws T;
}

<T extends Throwable> void invoke(Action<T> action) throws T
{
    action.doIt(); // throws T
}
```

If we invoke with an empty lambda, what would `T` be inferred as?

```
    invoke( ()->{} );
```

The only constraint on `T` is an upper bound `Throwable`. In earlier stage of java8, `T=Throwable` would be inferred. See this [report](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2013-February/007981.html) I filed.

But that is pretty silly, to infer `Throwable`, a checked exception, out of an empty block. A solution was proposed in the report (which is apparently adopted by JLS) -

```
If E has not been inferred from previous steps, and E is in the throw clause, 
and E has an upper constraint E<<X,
    if X:>RuntimeException, infer E=RuntimeException
    otherwise, infer E=X. (X is an Error or a checked exception)
```

i.e. if the upper bound is `Exception` or `Throwable`, choose `RuntimeException` as the solution. In this case, there *is* a good reason to choose a particular subtype of the upper bound.

Comment: What is the meaning of `X:>RuntimeException` in your last example snippet ?

Comment: @marsouf - X has a lower bound of RuntimeException.

Answer (score 1):

With `sneakyThrow`, the type `T` is a bounded generic type variable *without* a specific type (because there is no where the type could come from).

With `nonSneakyThrow`, the type `T` is the same type as the argument, thus in your example, the `T` of `nonSneakyThrow(e);` is `Exception`. As `testSneaky()` does not declare a thrown `Exception`, an error is shown.

Note that this is a known interference of Generics with checked exceptions.

Comment: So for `sneakyThrow` it isn't actually inferred to any specific type, and the "cast" is to such an undefined type? I wonder what actually happens with this.